# How do I compare two dates(different timezones) that I have in view( I can not set timezone parameter) in snowflake?

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I compare two dates(different timezones) that I have in view( I can not set timezone parameter) in snowflake ? Examples of dates to be compared is **"2021-12-02 06:00:56.000" < "2021-12-02 00:57:56.107 -0800"**.

The result should be **TRUE** as "2021-12-02 00:57:56.107 -0800" is "2021-12-02 08:57:56.107" which is greater than "2021-12-02 06:00:56.000".

When I simply try `SELECT '2021-12-02 06:00:56.000' < '2021-12-02 00:57:56.107 -0800'` this results in FALSE probably because it compares "2021-12-02 06:00:56.000" with ""2021-12-02 00:57:56.107" and does not take -0800 in account.

P.S. : "-0800" is not fixed so I can not hardcode -8 in dateadd function.

Comment: Have you tried to convert date to timestamp first and then compared these two timestamps?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT '2021-12-02 06:00:56.000' < convert_timezone('America/Los_Angeles', 'UTC','2021-12-02 00:57:56.107 -0800');
```

Use the convert_timezone function to convert from one timezone to another, depending on your location and preferred timezone that you want to use, eg. local or UTC.

More Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html#convert-timezone